# Join two lists using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']      
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# How can I get this result using list Comprehension
list3 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 1, 2, 3, 4]


list3 = [list1.append(x) for x in list2]
print(list3)

# returned
[None, None, None, None]
```

Comment: This is just `list3 = list1 + list2`.  A list comprehension is not relevant here.

Comment: Is there a reason you actually have to use a **comprehension** specifically for this?

Comment: no I was just curious if its possible or not ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
[*list1,*list2]

#['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

not sure if this will be called list comp

**Edit:**

Technically this fits the definition of list comprehension

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']      
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

list3 = [x for x in (*list1,*list2)]
#['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

but, why would you do this when you can simply do:

```
list3=list1+list2
```

Comment: It's not a list comprehension.

Comment: @khelwood yes you are right; I guess there must be a for loop in list comp?

Comment: The syntax of a list comprehension is `[? for ? in ?]` or `[? for ? in ? if ?]`

Comment: yes, I got it from the docs: *A list comprehension consists of brackets containing an expression followed by a for clause, then zero or more for or if clauses. The result will be a new list resulting from evaluating the expression in the context of the for and if clauses which follow it.*

Comment: I just wanted to know if its possible to use list comprehension to get the same result as list1 + list2

Comment: I was practicing list comprehension. Can you explain why do have '*' sing front of the variable?

Comment: Thank you 'God is One', For the solution it really helped.

Comment: @AlinKhan you are welcome. * is used for unpacking. You can see this link for explanation https://towardsdatascience.com/unpacking-operators-in-python-306ae44cd480

Answer (score -1):

See joining lists, from [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_join_lists.asp):

```
list1 = ["a", "b" , "c"]
list2 = [1, 2, 3]

list3 = list1 + list2
print(list3)
```

Answer (score -1):

Though the obvious way to do this is simple concatenation

```
list3 = list1 + list2
```

you can find a way to use a list comprehension if you must:

```
list3 = [x for lst in (list1, list2) for x in lst]
```

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 1, 2, 3, 4]
```